# Get common ManyToMany objects with django extra select

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

```
class Seller(object):
    type = ...
    name = ...
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car)

class PotentialBuyer(object):
    name = ...
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car)

class Car(object):
    extra_field = ...
    extra_field2 = ...
```

Suppose I have a relationship like this. I would like to use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) queryset modifier to get the list of cars that are already been picked out by PotentialBuyers when I fetch a seller object. I suppose the query queryset will something like this.

```
def markPending(self)
    return self.extra(select={'pending': 'select images from PotentialBuyer as t ...'})
```

How can I accomplish this? Is there a better way? I could fetch the seller object and the potential object and do sets, but I'd think it would be cleaner to make it handled by the database. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Exists` subquery expression will do what you want. Or at least it'll get you started on the right path. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) Or you might want to use an [aggregate to count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression) the number of them.

Edit: If you need to select the full objects rather than the count, existence or a single entity, then use a `Prefetch` instance in `prefetch_related`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

Comment: It seems like there are only examples of `Exists` being used for ForeignKey Relations and not ManyToMany and I am not sure how it can be applied here with the queryset using `OuterRef` to reference the related object. My use case seems to be a bit different as I am concerned with a ManyToMany field that is shared between two models.

Comment: If you edit your post to fully describe the query in `extra` and add any fields used on the models, I can probably help you write it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer, but this is the solution I ended up with and I am satisfied by the performance. Perhaps someone can answer the question later :

```
    from api.models import PotentialBuyer
    potentials = PotentialBuyer.objects.filter(owner=user_id, default=True).first().cars.all()
    Car.objects.filter(....).annotate(pending=Case(When(id__in=potentials, then=Value(True)), default=Value(False), output_field=BooleanField()))
```

Comment: Please look at `Exists` in the documentation. It's what you should be using. It'll reduce this to a single query. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries